# What is the ways to verify levels of microphone input in electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, web-audio-api

I am trying to develop desktop app with electron.

I am doing the task that I have to check microphone input level and run the function when there's more than certain level of input.

I have found some Github repositories however most of them requires other audio software like alsa (Linux).

So right now, Web Audio API seems like the right way to go but I don't see any related document or examples about it.

If it is possible can anyone show me the example with Web Audio API?
or just ideas can be helpful too.

If there's other way than Web Audio API that would be great too.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out by using Web Audio API analyzer!

```
var constraints = {audio: true};
var stream = null;

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(mediaStream){
  callbStream(mediaStream);
}).catch(function(err) { console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message); });

function callbStream(mediaStream){
  stream = mediaStream;
}

function getStreamData() {
  if(stream != null){
    var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    var source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.fftSize = 32;
    var dataArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.fftSize);
    setTimeout(function(){
      analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);
      console.log('V:' + dataArray[0] / 128.0);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

var animClock = setInterval(getStreamData, 1000);
```